# Trying to Edit a Page but it sends me to a Product Edit page

Tags: pages, editor, bug

I have the strangest issue that I encountered. I have updated the newest version of Wordpress and installed Google Analytics GADWP Plugin and Yoast SEO. (I don't think this is the issue though)

When i try to Edit a page from "Pages" section in the wp-admin

[image]

Instead of taking me to the correct page to edit the specific page it sends me to the edit section of the same product every time.

[image]

I am not sure what is going on and if anyone can help me fix this or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S.
Other pages are acting this way as well but it is being sent to a different product edit page.

Comment: Have you confirmed the plugin is not the issue by deactivating it and retesting? There's not enough information in your question to answer it at the moment

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for your response. Yes I have tried deactivating plugins one by one to see if it fixes it. Just a very strange issue how it redirects like that. It's even weirder because the "post=2165" is correct to the page i am trying to edit. I have cleared all caches on my browser and wordpress side. What other information do you think I should provide to help resolve this?

Comment: What is the url for the edit page link vs the edit product link for that product you keep getting sent to?

Comment: I think I located the problem. It looks like it is a theme issue. Thanks for all your help but I will have to resolve this with my theme provider "Divi" now unless anyone else knows a solution to this problem.